# Angular + signalR

Tags: c#, angular, signalr

Два дня потрачено...

Суть проблемы:
Пишется мини чат на angular с. использованием signalR (бэкенд на c#, restAPI).

Сейчас все работает когда приложение только запустилось, идем по адресу http://localhost:4200/messendger и нормально переписываемся. Как только перешли по другому адресу и вернулись обратно - сообщения в чате начинают дублироваться, если перейти опять на другую страницу и вернуться - то сообщений уже будет +3, ну и так далее.

Подписка на Observable отменяется вроде вовремя. Помогите плиз)

Код сервиса SignnalrService:

```
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NumberValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';

declare var $: any;
const subject = new Observable<number>();

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SignnalrService {

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { 

      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("https://localhost:5001/chatHub", {
          accessTokenFactory: () => {
            return this.token;
          }
        } as signalR.IHttpConnectionOptions)
       // .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

      Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1, });

     // this.connect();
    
  }

  public connect() {    
    
    if (this.hubConnection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {    
      this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }

  public disconnect() {
    this.hubConnection.stop();
  }

  private token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  private newMessageCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  public newMessage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);

  setSpinnerState(): void {
    this.newMessageCount.next(Number(this.newMessageCount.value) + 1);
  };

  public getNewMessageCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.newMessageCount;
  };

  public getNewMessage(): Observable<any> {

    this.hubConnection?.on('NewMessageText', (data) => {

      this.commonService.currentCompanyIdJson().subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (data.IdCompany == res) {
          this.setSpinnerState();
        } else {
          
        }
      });

      this.newMessage.next(data);

      return this.newMessage;
    });
   
    return this.newMessage;

  };

 
  public SendMessageText(message: any) {

    this.hubConnection?.invoke("SendMessageText", message)
      .then(() => {

      });
  }

}
```

Код компонента:

```
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-messenger',
  templateUrl: './messenger.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messenger.component.css']
})
export class MessengerComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('mychat') mychat: any;

  subscription?: Subscription;
  notifier = new Subject();
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService, public messangerServise: MessegerService, private signalRService: SignnalrService) { }

  allUsers: any;
  myGroups: any[] = [];
  myName: any;
  messages: any[] = [];
  currentIdGroup: any;
  currentGroupName: any;
  newMessage: any;
  myProfile: any;
  currentCheckedGroup: any; 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllUsers();
    this.getMyGroups(1);
    this.countHeight();
    this.getMyProfile();

   this.signalRService.newMessage
   .pipe(takeUntil(this.notifier))
   .subscribe(data =>{
     console.log(data);
   });


    this.subscription = this.signalRService.getNewMessage()
   .pipe(takeUntil(this.notifier))
    .subscribe(data => {     
       if (this.getcurrentCheckedGroup(data.messages?.IdGroup) == -1) {     
         this.getMyGroups();
       }
 
       var countIdGroup = parseInt($("#groupCountId_" + data.messages?.IdGroup).html());
 
       if (isNaN(countIdGroup)) {
         countIdGroup = 0;
       }
 
       countIdGroup = Number(countIdGroup) + 1;
 
       $("#groupCountId_" + data.messages?.IdGroup).html(countIdGroup);
       if (this.currentIdGroup === data.messages?.IdGroup && this.currentIdGroup != null) {
         var newMes = {
           id: data.messages?.Id,
           id_group: data.messages?.IdGroup,
           id_tip: data.messages?.IdType,
           id_sender: data.messages?.IdSender,
           datetime: data.messages?.Datetime,
           value: data.messages?.Value,
           myid: data.messages?.MyId,
           name_user: data.NameUser,
           otchestvo: data.Otchestvo,
           familia: data.FamilyUser,
           val: null
         }
 
         this.messages.push(newMes); 
 
         setTimeout(function () {
           var div = $("#myChat");
           div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
         }, 1);
       }     
     });     
  }

  ngOnDestroy() : void {    

   this.notifier.next();
   this.notifier.complete();
   this.notifier.unsubscribe();

   this.destroy$.next(true);
   this.destroy$.unsubscribe(); 

   this.subscription?.unsubscribe();

  }

  getMyProfile() {
    this.commonService.getMyProfile().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.myProfile = res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.myProfile = [];
      }
    );
  }


  sendMes() {
    var txt = $("#message").val();

    if (txt == "")
      return;

    var message = {
      IdGroup: this.currentIdGroup,
      Value: txt
    }

    this.signalRService.SendMessageText(message);
    $("#message").val('');
    $('#message').attr('rows', 1);

    var curDate = new Date();

    var newMes = {
      id: "",
      id_group: this.currentIdGroup,
      id_type: 1,
      id_sender: this.myProfile.id_user,
      datetime: curDate,
      value: txt,
      myid: this.myProfile.id_user,
      name_user: this.myProfile.nameUser,
      otchestvo: this.myProfile.otchestvo,
      familia: this.myProfile.familia,
      val: null
    }

    this.messages.push(newMes);
    setTimeout(function () {
      var div = $("#myChat");
      div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
    }, 1);

  }

  ReadMessages() {    
    this.signalRService.ReadMessInGroup(this.currentIdGroup);   

  }

}
```

Comment: не в тему, но правильно пишется `messenger`

Comment: Пока не понятно, что точно может быть. Стоит проверить, вызывается ли у вас метод `OnDestroy()`, вдруг компонент не умер.

Comment: OnDestroy() вызывается

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ:

```
ngOnDestroy() : void {
 
    this.signalRService.hubConnection?.off('NewMessageText');
}
```

Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

Comment: хм.. вчера точно этим же занимался =)
пойду протестирую этот кейс, спасибо!